# Error while calling Discovery service in conversation-with-discoveryapplication

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, watson-discovery

I have used https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery code and deployed application in Bluemix, when I am testing the application conversation is working but discovery service is not working .

I have added OUT_OF_Scope intent with call_discovery action.

I am getting server is busy error when we give out scope question in chatbot.

below is the  the log error , please help me to resolve this error.
Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.watson.apis.conversation_with_discovery.rest.ProxyResource.postMessage:192'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.watson.apis.conversation_with_discovery.rest.ProxyResource.pos

Answer (score 0):

When I used the conversation-with-discovery I had the same problem, but I see within the Github the solution for this: Switch to the `liberty-for-java_v3_7-20170118-2046` buildpack that doesn't have problems with the Java SDK.

Reference: [IBM Developer](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery/issues/83)